# Address already in use with NettyAcceptor in HornetQ

Tags: java, spring, netty, hornetq

I am developing one Spring application server with HotnetQ embedded to pubsub service. I have the next class described more below to manager HornetQ server.

But, when I deploy my application I get the next error in tomcat console.

I have been changing Netty acceptor port number, but problem persist, If I use other acceptor instead Netty it work fine, but I am interested in Netty Acceptor type.

```
Setting ServerMQ configuration...
Initializing ServerMQ...
mar 12, 2014 1:42:44 PM org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl start
INFO: HQ221000: live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/largemessages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
mar 12, 2014 1:42:44 PM org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl initialisePart1
WARN: HQ222007: Security risk! HornetQ is running with the default cluster admin user and default password. Please see the HornetQ user guide, cluster chapter, for instructions on how to change this.
mar 12, 2014 1:42:44 PM org.hornetq.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl <init>
INFO: HQ221043: Adding protocol support CORE
ServerMQ initialized!
mar 12, 2014 1:42:44 PM org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl$SharedNothingLiveActivation run
ERROR: HQ224000: Failure in initialisation
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:479)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadHandler.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1000)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:457)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.bind(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:842)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:194)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:331)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

mar 12, 2014 1:42:44 PM org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl start
INFO: HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.4.1.Final (Fast Hornet, 124) [a681c9b2-a83a-11e3-b8ef-531df38c9cfa]
```

Here is my class implementation.

```
@Component(value = "serverMQ")
public class ServerMQ extends EmbeddedHornetQ {

    // Server config.
    private Configuration config;

    private ClientSessionFactory clientSessionFactory;

    public ServerMQ() {

        System.out.println("Setting ServerMQ configuration...");

        // Instantiate server config.
        this.config = new ConfigurationImpl();

        // Server has persistence for messages.
        this.config.setPersistenceEnabled(false);

        // Server has user security authentication.
        this.config.setSecurityEnabled(false);

        Map<String, Object> nettyAcceptorParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        nettyAcceptorParams.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "localhost");
        nettyAcceptorParams.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, 5555);

        this.config.getAcceptorConfigurations().clear();

        this.config.getAcceptorConfigurations().add(new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), nettyAcceptorParams));
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        try {

            System.out.println("Initializing ServerMQ...");

            this.setConfiguration(this.config);
            this.start();

            System.out.println("ServerMQ initialized!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.err.println("ServerMQ initializing error:\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

After **@***Clebert* suggestion I have changed my ServerMQ class to try new way to implementation pubsub service as you can see below... Same problem...

```
@Component(value = "serverMQ")
public class ServerMQ {

    // Server config.
    private Configuration config;

    // HornetQ Server
    private EmbeddedHornetQ mQServer;

    private ClientSessionFactory clientSessionFactory;
public ServerMQ() {

    System.out.println("Setting ServerMQ configuration...");

    // Instantiate server config.
    this.config = new ConfigurationImpl();

    // Server has persistence for messages.
    this.config.setPersistenceEnabled(false);

    // Server has user security authentication.
    this.config.setSecurityEnabled(false);

    Map<String, Object> nettyAcceptorAttrs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    nettyAcceptorAttrs.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "localhost");
    nettyAcceptorAttrs.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, 5555);

    /*
     HashSet<TransportConfiguration> transports = new HashSet<TransportConfiguration>();
     transports.add(new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), nettyAcceptorParams));
     transports.add(new TransportConfiguration(InVMAcceptorFactory.class.getName()));
     */

    this.config.getAcceptorConfigurations().clear();

    this.config.getAcceptorConfigurations().add(new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), nettyAcceptorAttrs));

    this.init2();
}

public void init2() {

    try {

        System.out.println("Initializing ServerMQ...");

        this.mQServer = new EmbeddedHornetQ();

        this.mQServer.setConfiguration(this.config);
        this.mQServer.start();
        /*
         this.clientSessionFactory = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(
         new TransportConfiguration(
         InVMConnectorFactory.class.getName())).createSessionFactory();
         */
        System.out.println("ServerMQ initialized!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.err.println("ServerMQ initializing error:\n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are starting two servers!

Your class is extending EmbeddedHornetQ which also has a hornetQServer being started..

on your subclass you are then starting a new server.

The difference is that EmbeddedServer on the super class is using the file Configuration parser and an xml while your version is doing everything from scratch.

Fix your code and only start one server!

After your second iteration, I ran your code as a main class and it worked here.

```
package org.hornetq.tests.integration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration;
import org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClientSessionFactory;
import org.hornetq.core.config.Configuration;
import org.hornetq.core.config.impl.ConfigurationImpl;
import org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory;
import org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.TransportConstants;
import org.hornetq.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedHornetQ;

public class ServerMQ
{

   // Server config.
   private Configuration config;

   // HornetQ Server
   private EmbeddedHornetQ mQServer;

   private ClientSessionFactory clientSessionFactory;

   public ServerMQ()
   {

      System.out.println("Setting ServerMQ configuration...");

      // Instantiate server config.
      this.config = new ConfigurationImpl();

      // Server has persistence for messages.
      this.config.setPersistenceEnabled(false);

      // Server has user security authentication.
      this.config.setSecurityEnabled(false);

      Map<String, Object> nettyAcceptorAttrs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      nettyAcceptorAttrs.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "localhost");
      nettyAcceptorAttrs.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, 5555);

    /*
     HashSet<TransportConfiguration> transports = new HashSet<TransportConfiguration>();
     transports.add(new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), nettyAcceptorParams));
     transports.add(new TransportConfiguration(InVMAcceptorFactory.class.getName()));
     */

      this.config.getAcceptorConfigurations().clear();

      this.config.getAcceptorConfigurations().add(new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), nettyAcceptorAttrs));

      this.init2();
   }

   public void init2()
   {

      try
      {

         System.out.println("Initializing ServerMQ...");

         this.mQServer = new EmbeddedHornetQ();

         this.mQServer.setConfiguration(this.config);
         this.mQServer.start();
        /*
         this.clientSessionFactory = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(
         new TransportConfiguration(
         InVMConnectorFactory.class.getName())).createSessionFactory();
         */
         System.out.println("ServerMQ initialized!");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

         System.err.println("ServerMQ initializing error:\n" + ex.getMessage());
      }
   }
```

Main class

```
   public static void main(String arg[])
   {
      ServerMQ mq = new ServerMQ();

      try
      {
         Thread.sleep(10000);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
```

You either now have spring calling init for your... you are having the server being started twice.. or you have two configurations on your xml that's being executed from Embedded.

Or maybe you have a dead process somewhere in your system. Try rebooting your server.. or check if there is anything else using the port you configured.

Comment: Problem persist with new approach.

Comment: I am really frustrated. I am debugging my app on deploy, setting breakpoint in setConfiguration() line, just before start(), when runtime execution is stopped in the breakpoint, I see with netstat all busys ports, 5555 not appear, it's free. but just when I execute start() get the same error again. Who is normal, just after execute start() line I can see one new java.exe process which is listening on 5555.

Comment: Your code runs fine with a main class here. Try a simple approach (using the main class I provided) and then add Spring. It really seems you are starting two servers or the embedded at your place is getting a XML or something. It's environmental I would say. Simple debug would fix that easily. Just check how many servers are running... or look at the NettyAcceptor on HornetQ being started.

Comment: @Dani SOF is not a support ticket system that you award points if someone solves your problem. The question has been answered. if you can't find the issue in your code.. it's not a problem with the question...

You should accept the answer, and open a forum on hornetQ user's forum with a running example where we can help you better.

Comment: I fixed the problem a few days ago, But I am working yet in the new approach. When I have it I will post here as solution.